(Proof review) The product of symmetric unimodal polynomials is again symmetric unimodal.
I am reviewing Stanley's proof (an elegant proof) that the product of unimodal symmetric polynomials is itself unimodal and symmetric.
In the proof, he defines $F(q) = \sum_{i=0}^m a_i q^i$, $G(q) = \sum_{j=0}^n b_j q^j$, $r=\lfloor m/2\rfloor$ and $s=\lfloor n/2\rfloor$. He realizes that both sums can be expressed as telescopic sums: $\sum_{i=0}^r \sum_{k=i}^{n-i} (a_i - a_{i-1}) q^k$ and $G(q) = \sum_{j=0}^s \sum_{k=j}^{m-j} (b_j - b_{j-1}) q^k$ (if you need me to explain this in more detail, I would be happy to do so).
Then he expresses the product as $\sum_{i=0}^r \sum_{j=0}^s (a_i - a_{i-1})(b_j - b_{j-1})(q^i + \cdots + q^{m-i})(q^j + \cdots + q^{n-j}),$ and concludes that it is symmetric and unimodal. This is because the product $(q^i + \cdots + q^{m-i})(q^j + \cdots + q^{n-j})$ is symmetric around the same peak $(m+n)/2$ and unimodal. Seeing the symmetry of this product is easy, but it is not clear to me why it is unimodal.
I fully understand the structure of the proof, but I do not understand this particular point. The best I have managed to do is to express this product as $$(q^i + \cdots + q^{m-i})(q^j + \cdots + q^{n-j}) = \sum_{k=i+j}^{m+n-i-j} c_k q^k,$$ where $c_k = \min(m - i, k - j) - \max(i, k - (n - j)) + 1$. I want to show that $c_k - c_{k-1} \geq 0$ for $i+j \leq k \leq (m+n)/2$. I am stuck, and I would appreciate your help.

We assume wlog $m\leq n$. We factor out $q^i$ and $q^j$ which has no effect on unimodality and we consider
\begin{align*}
&\left(1+q+q^2+\cdots+q^{m-2i}\right)\left(1+q+q^2+\cdots+q^{n-2j}\right)\\
&\qquad=\frac{1-q^{m-2i+1}}{1-q}\cdot \frac{1-q^{n-2j+1}}{1-q}\\
&\qquad=\frac{1-q^{m-2i+1}-q^{n-2j+1}+q^{m+n-2i-2j+2}}{(1-q)^2}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
We let $a:=m-2i+1, b:=n-2j+1$. Denoting with $[q^t]$ the coefficient of $q^t$ of a series and expanding the denominator in (1) we get
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{[q^t]}&\color{blue}{\left(1-q^a-q^b+q^{a+b}\right)\left(1+2q+3q^2+\cdots\right)}\\
&=\left([q^t]-[q^{t-a}]-[q^{t-b}]+[q^{t-a-b}]\right)\left(1+2q+3q^2+\cdots\right)\\
&=\begin{cases}
t+1&\qquad 0\leq t<a\\
(t+1)-(t-a+1)&\qquad a\leq t<b\\
(t+1)-(t-a+1)-(t-b+1)&\qquad b\leq t<a+b\\
(t+1)-(t-a+1)-(t-b+1)+(t-a-b+1)&\qquad t\geq a+b
\end{cases}\\
&\,\color{blue}{=\begin{cases}
t+1&\qquad 0\leq t<a\\
a&\qquad a\leq t<b\\
a+b-(t+1)&\qquad b\leq t<a+b\\
0&\qquad t\geq a+b
\end{cases}}
\end{align*}

We conclude the product of the polynomials
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\left(1+q+q^2+\cdots+q^{m-2i}\right)\left(1+q+q^2+\cdots+q^{n-2j}\right)}
\end{align*}
has increasing coefficients up to $q^{a-1}=q^{m-2i}$, a maximum coefficient $a=m-2i+1$ up to $q^{b-1}$ and decreasing coeffcients up to $q^{a+b-1}$ showing that the product is unimodal and therefore also the product when multiplied by $q^{i+j}$.

Note: If we consider small cases of $m$ and $n$ and simply multiply them out, the assertion becomes obvious. Perhaps this is what Stanley had in mind.
